# Plotting 60hz data signal acquired using mpchart

Tags: android, graph, bluetooth, signal-processing, mpandroidchart

Hy guys, I'm acquiring a 60hz signal through arduino's adc and sending a float buffer to my app. When I export the data from arduino  to a csv file everything works fine, the shape of the wave is really great, but when I try to plot that buffer in my app using mpchart libs it is getting a kind of broken. Does anyone can help me to solve that? Bellow follows my code and the image of the graph

Arduino's code:

```
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#define sensorPin A1


#ifndef cbi
#define cbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) &= ~_BV(bit))
#endif

#ifndef sbi
#define sbi(sfr, bit) (_SFR_BYTE(sfr) |= _BV(bit))
#endif

void setup() {
  //configure pins 14,15 of arduino mega to serial TX/RX respectively
  SoftwareSerial bluetooth(14, 15);


  //configure AD pins for 9600 hz;
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS2);
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS1);
  sbi(ADCSRA, ADPS0);
  Serial1.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  while (1) {
    float vector[400];
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i++) {
      vector[i] = floatMap(analogRead(sensorPin), 0, 1023, 0, 5);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 400; i = i++) {
      Serial1.print('#');
      Serial1.print(vector[i],2);
      delay(30);
    }
  }
}


float floatMap(float x, float inMin, float inMax, float outMin, float outMax) {
  return (x - inMin) * (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) + outMin;
}

int procura_inic(int vector[]) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 319; i++) {
    if (vector[i] == 0 && (vector[i + 1] > vector[i])) {
      return i;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Bluetooth Receiving Function

```
 public void run() {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
                int bytes = 0;
                int begin = 0;// bytes returned from read()
                while (true) {
                    try {

                        bytes += mmInStream.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
                        //This loop is responsible for  message sending.
                        for(int i = begin; i < bytes; i++) {
                                mHandler.obtainMessage(
                                        MESSAGE_READ, begin, i, buffer).sendToTarget();
                                begin = i + 1;
                                if(i == bytes - 1) {
                                    bytes = 0;
                                    begin = 0;
                                }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Tracking Function

```
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            switch(msg.what) {
                case Bluetooth.SUCCESS_CONNECT:
                    Bluetooth.connectedThread = new Bluetooth.ConnectedThread((BluetoothSocket) msg.obj);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Conectado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String s = "Successfully connected";
                    Bluetooth.connectedThread.start();
                    break;
                case Bluetooth.MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String strIncome = new String(readBuffer,0,5);

                    //aux = Float.parseFloat(strIncome);
                    if(strIncome.indexOf('#') == 0 && strIncome.indexOf('.') == 2) {
                        strIncome = strIncome.replace("#", "");
                        aux = Float.parseFloat(strIncome);
                        addEntry(aux);


                    }
                    break;

            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Can u show us how the ideal wave shape from the csv looks like ? Did you consider the x - axis scaling ? The mpchart x-axis scale might be giving you a detailed graph. Check the reference graph's x axis scaling and let me know if it matches.